# Plotting solution for quadratic equation

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This is my primer time using matlab especially plotting.

I try to plot the solutions for `y = x^2 − x − 2` like in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Polynomialdeg2.svg)

[image]

But I don't know how to model  this plot  in matlab (it makes sense because the solutions must be computed first) but shouldn't the shape of curve will remain the same.

I tried:

```
clc;
close all;

%y = x2 − x − 2
x = [-3:1:3];

y= x.^2 - x -2;
plot(y), grid on;
```

But the curve I got is totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're choosing wrong points for drawing the curve.

The image that you showed above takes the values of `x` in the interval `[-2,3]`. Fixing this gives exactly the same curve as that of the one in the question. 

 Also note that the minima of your function is at `x=0.5`. So, if `x` has equal number of values less than `0.5` and  greater than `0.5`, you will get the curve of the desired shape.

**Code:**

```
x = [-2:0.01:3];  %Choosing 0.01, because more the points, more the curve will be accurate
y= x.^2 - x -2;
plot(x,y), grid on;
```

**Output:**

[image: output]